# unity ads not showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

My Unity Ads in test mode Not Showing I thought was in my code but it wasn't when i get game id from youtube video it worked should unity test ads work with game id after days or after i make it

My Cdoe

```
public void PlayAd()
{
    Debug.Log(gameId);
    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad is ready");
        Advertisement.Show("video");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Ad is not ready");
    }
}
```

when ads not showing i get ad is ready how ads is ready and not showing event test ads